# Parse json output in batch

Tags: json, batch-file

I am trying to get the values of name field `where user_comment=<something I supply to the batch script>`

```
{"snapshots":[{"name":"JqJiP","user_comment":"Clean_image","current":"n","created":"2020-03-14"},{"name":"N4bk7","user_comment":"Import","current":"n","created":"2020-03-16"},{"name":"jOtfa","user_comment":"Baseline","current":"y","created":"2020-03-20"}]}
{"snapshots":[{"name":"dcLD5","user_comment":"Clean_image","current":"n","created":"2020-03-14"},{"name":"tO8hN","user_comment":"Import","current":"n","created":"2020-03-16"},{"name":"yOgNY","user_comment":"Baseline","current":"y","created":"2020-03-20"}]}
```

For example if I want to get the value of `"user_comment":"Clean_image"`

The output should be

> JqJiP
>
> dcLD5

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch doesn't understand JSON, so you'd have to use a tool that does. [`xidel`](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) is such a tool.

```
xidel -s input.json -e "$json/(snapshots)()[user_comment='Clean_image']/name"
JqJiP
dcLD5
```

`$json`: The file content parsed as JSON.
`(snapshots)()`: All objects within the `snapshots`-arrays.
`[user_comment='Clean_image']`: Only those objects that have a `user_comment`-attribute with a value "Clean_image".
`name`: The value of the `name`-attribute within those objects.

See also this [online Xidel demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%7B%22snapshots%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22JqJiP%22%2C%22user_comment%22%3A%22Clean_image%22%2C%22current%22%3A%22n%22%2C%22created%22%3A%222020-03-14%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22N4bk7%22%2C%22user_comment%22%3A%22Import%22%2C%22current%22%3A%22n%22%2C%22created%22%3A%222020-03-16%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22jOtfa%22%2C%22user_comment%22%3A%22Baseline%22%2C%22current%22%3A%22y%22%2C%22created%22%3A%222020-03-20%22%7D%5D%7D%0A%7B%22snapshots%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22dcLD5%22%2C%22user_comment%22%3A%22Clean_image%22%2C%22current%22%3A%22n%22%2C%22created%22%3A%222020-03-14%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22tO8hN%22%2C%22user_comment%22%3A%22Import%22%2C%22current%22%3A%22n%22%2C%22created%22%3A%222020-03-16%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22yOgNY%22%2C%22user_comment%22%3A%22Baseline%22%2C%22current%22%3A%22y%22%2C%22created%22%3A%222020-03-20%22%7D%5D%7D&=&extract=%24json%2F(snapshots)()%5Buser_comment%3D%27Clean_image%27%5D%2Fname&=%24json%2F(snapshots)()%5Buser_comment%3D%27Clean_image%27%5D%2Fname&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto).